Add Label management to Metis through an administration interface
I want to add Label management to "thetis" ,which is a custom framework through an administration interface.
First, what steps should I take in order to initially achieve the transfer of these files from the project that is now in the "thetis" project so that it can be used by other projects as well. and instead using the i3label .properties ,to be able to connect directly to the database and get the information from there and  displays it to the user. Thank you very much
1)my model is :
package org.primecognition.lode.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.primecognition.base.anno.ModelMandatory;
import org.primecognition.base.anno.ModelSystemParameter;
import org.primecognition.base.model.DefaultNamedEntity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
@Entity @javax.persistence.Cacheable(true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ModelSystemParameter
public class I18NLabel extends DefaultNamedEntity 
{

    @ModelMandatory
    public String language;
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getId()+"-"+getName();
    }
}

2)my repo :
package org.primecognition.app.repo;


import org.primecognition.lode.model.I18NLabel;
import org.apache.deltaspike.data.api.FullEntityRepository;
import org.apache.deltaspike.data.api.Repository;
import org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.Transactional;
import org.primecognition.base.persistence.jpa.IFilterTokenQuerySupport;

@Transactional
@Repository(forEntity = I18NLabel.class)
public interface IRepoI18NLabel extends FullEntityRepository<I18NLabel, Long>,IFilterTokenQuerySupport<I18NLabel>
{
    int removeById(Long id);
}

3)my service :
package org.primecognition.app.svc;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primecognition.app.repo.IRepoI18NLabel;
import org.primecognition.base.persistence.QueryParams;
import org.primecognition.base.util.SearchUtils;
import org.primecognition.lode.model.I18NLabel;
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class SvcI18NLabel {

    @Inject
    IRepoI18NLabel repo;
    
    public List<I18NLabel> findAll()
    {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public I18NLabel findById(Long uid)
    {
        return repo.findBy(uid);
    }

    public I18NLabel save(I18NLabel source)
    {
        return repo.merge(source);
    }

    public int deleteById(Long id)
    {
        return repo.removeById(id);
    }
    
    public List<I18NLabel> filter(QueryParams qParams)
    {
        return repo.filter(qParams);
    }
    
    public Map<String, List<Object>> getSearchOptions(String entityClassSimpleName, String[] fields)
    {
        return SearchUtils.getSearchOptions(repo.getEntityManagerFactory(), entityClassSimpleName, fields) ;
    }
}

4)my controller:
package org.primecognition.ui.ctrl;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.primecognition.app.svc.SvcI18NLabel;
import org.primecognition.base.persistence.QueryParams;
import org.primecognition.base.ui.ctrl.CtrlDefaultAttica;

import org.primecognition.lode.model.I18NLabel;
import org.primecognition.ui.renderer.DataTableRenderer;
import org.primecognition.ui.util.AtticaP;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.WireVariable;

public class CtrlI18NLabel  extends CtrlDefaultAttica<I18NLabel>
{
    @WireVariable
    SvcI18NLabel svcI18NLabel;
    
    public CtrlI18NLabel()
    {
        super(I18NLabel.class);
        setEditForm(String.format(AtticaP.UI_EDIT_FORM_NAME_PATTERN, getEntityClass().getSimpleName()));
        setEnhancedFiltering(true);
        setMultiCheckmark(false);
        browserVisibleFields = new String[]{"name","descr"};
    }
    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception
    {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        DataTableRenderer dataTableRenderer = new DataTableRenderer();
        dataTableRenderer.setRowSelection(isMultiCheckmark());
        getBrowser().setItemRenderer(dataTableRenderer);
    }
    @Override
    public List<I18NLabel> getBrowserData(QueryParams qParams) {
        return svcI18NLabel.filter(qParams);
    }
    
    @Override
    public I18NLabel insert() {
        return svcI18NLabel.save(new I18NLabel());
    }
    
    @Override
    public int delete(Long id) {
        return svcI18NLabel.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, List<Object>> getSearchOptions() {
        
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}```
5)also i have this(labels are found from a database for the UI (user interface) of an application):




@Slf4j
public class DatabaseCommentLabelLocator implements org.zkoss.util.resource.LabelLocator2 {
private ServletContext _svlctx;
private String _name;
String[] packagesToSearch = new String[] { "org.primecognition" };

public DatabaseCommentLabelLocator(ServletContext svlctx, String name) {
    _svlctx = svlctx;
    _name = name;
}

@Override
public String getCharset() {
    return "UTF8";
}

public InputStream locate(Locale locale) {
    String dsName = "jdbc/dsMain";

//      if (sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("datasource.name") != null)
//      {
//          dsName = sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("datasource.name");
//      }
    // Map<String, String> mappings = getTableColumnToClasssMappings();

    try {
        Connection conn = getDatasource(dsName).getConnection();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        {
            // column comments
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT NAME,DESCR FROM I18NLABEL");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String labelName = rs.getString("NAME");
                String labelDescription = rs.getString("DESCR");
                sb.append(labelName).append("=").append(labelDescription).append("\r\n");
            }
        }
        log.trace(sb.toString());
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public DataSource getDatasource(String datasource) {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ((Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup(datasource);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    return dataSource;
}

public Map<String, String> getTableColumnToClasssMappings() {
    Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String pkg : packagesToSearch) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(pkg, Scanners.TypesAnnotated);
        Set<Class<?>> entityClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
        for (Class<?> ec : entityClasses) {
            String tableName;
            Table annoTable = ec.getAnnotation(Table.class);
            if (annoTable != null)
                tableName = annoTable.name();
            else
                tableName = ec.getSimpleName();

            Map<String, Field> fieldMap = Reflection.getAllDeclaredFields(ec);
            for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()) {
                String colName;
                Field f = fieldMap.get(fieldName);
                Column annoCol = f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
                JoinColumn annoJoinCol = f.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class);
                if (annoCol != null) {
                    colName = annoCol.name();
                } else if (annoJoinCol != null) {
                    colName = annoJoinCol.name();
                } else
                    colName = f.getName();

                mappings.put(tableName.toLowerCase() + "." + colName.toLowerCase(),
                        ec.getSimpleName() + "." + f.getName());
                mappings.put(tableName.toLowerCase() + ".TITLE", ec.getSimpleName() + ".TITLE");

            }
        }
    }

    return mappings;
}

}```

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
